# URL applicationWillTerminate objective C

Tags: objective-c

I been trying to execute or request a url, inside de applicationWillTerminate event, but when i do it, the other functions, like:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
             willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request            redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse {
  [baseURL autorelease];
  baseURL = [[request URL] retain];
  return request;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

they doesn't get executed, i guess because, the last function or event executed it is applicationWillTerminate. Is there a way to reach or do it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue yesterday, and solved it using the snippet of code below:

```
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSString* requestUrlString = <your URL>;
NSMutableURLRequest *syncRequest  = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:syncRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised indeed if you were able to pull this off. `applicationWillTerminate` isn't lying! Sure you can set up a request and send it, but once that method returns there's no way your delegate(s) are going to be hanging around long enough to receive and respond to callbacks.

I'm afraid that you'll probably have to find another way to achieve what you need.

Comment: I already debug, the code, when i enter to the app, (login) execute the url, a logout url, to advice the server about that exit, and then the process got down. It works correctly. The problem begins when i try to do this in applicationWillTerminate, when i run the url with my logout, the methods to execute the url, doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation for the [applicationWillTerminate delegate method for UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) states that your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform tasks and return. Calling a method that uses the network and will run for an undetermined amount of time seems to violate the intent of the method.

Comment: I have to let know the server that i get logged out, to do this, i have to run the url. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, based on the Apple documentation, I think you shouldn't use any network communication that is delegate-based. So maybe you can come up with another way to send one-way network traffic that doesn't involve retrieving data or a complicated transaction like authentication. What kind of server is it?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, let me check what kind of server i been using, in that words, how can i check the kind of server, what do you mean ?

Comment: Well, I mean is it a web application?  What does your app do with the network (before it has to terminate anyway)?

Comment: Yes, it is a web service. It doesn't have to do anything just to execute to let know the server that i get out.

Answer (score 0):

A useful technique at this point is to simply save a flag that says "on the next startup, the app needs to run this URL request." Then, the next time the app starts, if the flag is true, run the URL request.  That might not be appropriate for every situation, but it has the advantage of having enough time to run.

Comment: In fact, i already been executing the url when the user get login, but the problem is that if you never try to enter the app thread get hung.